# Data mining library for hadoop

Tags: hadoop, data-mining, mahout

I am using Mahout for dataminng algorithms in hadoop. but it has bug in some cases.Is there any other data mining library that works with hadoop?
Thanks.

Comment: I personally haven't found anything better than Mahout for use cases where it fits. Switching from something good just because of few bugs is not a sensible thing, IMHO. If that is the case you will ask the same question for Hadoop one day. Which is software in this world is 100% bug free?

Comment: Are you sure you need Hadoop support? You can use Hadoop to load and preprocess your data, and then analyze it on a single node. Unless you have Google scale data, this may just work (and be a lot faster).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Spark](http://spark-project.org/)? It's a very efficient open source cluster computing system, both fast to run and fast to write. For distributed data mining, Spark is a very good tool.

Hope helpes!